# Notify peer reviewer about a flag he didn't raise

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, comments, late-answers

I just performed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17186756) and flagged the answer as *not an answer* because the person asked for help in their answer.

Then I noticed a comment by another user:

> Please explain your question properly. It is hard to understand what
>   you have tried and what is not working.

This is false feedback (questions must not be asked in answers) and sounded like it was written by a reviewer. So I checked out the commentator's profile and viewed [his review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17186504). I couldn't find any evidence of him raising a flag. That is why I replied to the commentator:

> @CalculatingMachine Pay attention with your reviews! This was posted
>   as answer. You were lucky this was not a test.

Yes, I did note the missing *an* in my reply.

I then sent of my review. Curious as I am I went back to my review summary and wanted to see the evidence of me raising a flag in that review. However, there is no evidence, at least not visible to me.

1. Are flags raised by other people only visible to people with higher rep? I am pretty sure these flags need to be visible in other review queues. And these queues are not only worked through by mods.
2. Should I just walk away when I see something like this? How would you have reacted to this scenario? Assuming you have the same priviledges as I currently have. (My rep is 1,780)
3. Did I make a mistake and the person actually raised a flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Are flags raised by other people only visible to people with higher rep? I am pretty sure these flags need to be visible in other review queues. And these queues are not only worked through by mods.

Completed reviews never show an indication that a flag was raised. Not even moderators see this information on that page (although we have other ways to find out).

All it shows on [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17186504) is which button was clicked to dispatch that review. In this case, the reviewer clicked "I'm Done", and that got recorded as "Reviewed". It doesn't record that they raised a flag (or left a comment or anything else) *before* clicking "I'm Done".

As a moderator, yes, I would *very much* prefer that detailed information about which action(s) were taken be visible right on that page, but other reviewers should *not* see this. The flags you raise are confidential (seen only by you and the moderators), and even though exposing that you *did* raise a flag isn't exactly the same thing as exposing *which* flag you raised, it's still an unnecessary leak of that user's privacy.

> 2. Should I just walk away when I see something like this? How would you have reacted to this scenario? Assuming you have the same priviledges as I currently have. (My rep is 1,780)

You should not make any assumptions about whether or not another user flagged something. As stated above, flags are confidential. You have no way of knowing whether someone raised a flag.

However, it was reasonable for you to comment on what you *were* able to observe—namely, the incorrect comment. Advising someone to make the question clearer in an answer is...not useful advice. At best, a comment like this creates noise; at worst, it sews confusion. So there's nothing wrong with advising that other user not to leave such comments and flag these answers instead.

I would have phrased it a bit differently than you did, though. Try something like:

> @CalculatingMachine This was actually posted as an answer, not a question! It didn't need to be clarified, it needed to be flagged as "not an answer".

Less focus on the smackdown ("pay attention"); more focus on the correct action.

You don't *have* to worry about catching or handling this type of thing, though. If someone has a history of incorrect reviews, a moderator will catch it and reach out to the user.

> 3. Did I make a mistake and the person actually raised a flag?

Flags are confidential. :-)

Good news is the post has been handled now.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about their confidentiality. Is that documented somewhere? I though I was missing some place on SO where I could see raised flags. And you are right about my comment. I could have been more precise and less "*in your face*".

Comment: @NoelWidmer You can see your own flags through your own user profile page. Click on "X helpful flags" on the right side of the page.

Comment: @duskwuff I know that. I was interested in seeing flags from other users.